# Probability of Dealing cards

Tags: probability, combinatorics, card-games

Randomly distributing 10 cards from a standard deck of 52 cards to 2 players, Xavier and Zorro, so each player gets 5 cards. 
(a) If Xavier has two Ace cards, find the probability that Zorro has at least one Ace card.
(b) Is the event that Xavier gets an Ace independent of the event that Zorro gets a Spade.

For part (a), If X already had 2 Aces, there are only 2 more Aces left for Z to choose from. For Z to have at least 1 Ace, Z can have 1 out of 2 Aces and 4 out of 48 non-Ace cards or both Aces and 3 non-Ace cards. So the number of possibilities is C(2,1)C(48,4) + C(2,2)C(48,3) = 406,456. However, the number of possibilities that X has 2 Aces is C(2,2)C(48,3) = 17,296. This is how far I can do. I've learned the conditional prob that says P(A|B) = P(A and B)/P(B) but not quite sure what is the difference between P(Z|X) and P(Z and X) for this problem.

For part (b), I know that to proof independence, I need to proof that P(A|B) = P(A). P(X gets an Ace) = C(4,1)C(48,4)/C(52,5) = 778,320/2,598,960 = 0.2995.
As for P(X gets an Ace | Z gets a Spade), I'm not sure how to do because there is one card which is an Ace of Spade. But my sense is they may not be independent, just can't proof it mathematically.

Comment: Hey and welcome to MSE! Any own thoughts about this problem?

Comment: What is a "Space"?

Comment: Sorry, I meant "Zorro gets a Spade"

Comment: Both of these should be routine calculations.  What have you done yourself to attempt this problem?  Have you ever encountered conditional probability before and do you know the necessary definitions to talk about conditional probabilities?  Are you able to calculate the probability that X gets two aces, completely ignoring Z for now?  Are you able to calculate the probability that Z gets at least one ace if instead of a usual deck of 52 cards which had four aces in it, we were to instead use a deck with only 47 cards which had only two aces in it?

Comment: Answer my questions in my previous comment with something other than "Nothing, no, no, no and no" and then we can work towards crafting an answer.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes, to get 5 cards with at least one ace out of 47 cards with 2 Aces, it's C(2,1)C(45,4) + C(2,2)C(45,3)

Answer (score 1):

> For part (a), If X already had 2 Aces, there are only 2 more Aces left for Z to choose from. For Z to have at least 1 Ace, Z can have 1 out of 2 Aces and 4 out of 48 non-Ace cards or both Aces and 3 non-Ace cards. So the number of possibilities is C(2,1)C(48,4) + C(2,2)C(48,3) = 406,456. However, the number of possibilities that X has 2 Aces is C(2,2)C(48,3) = 17,296. This is how far I can do.

You do not need the last.

You have counted favoured outcomes (Zorro is dealt at least one ace; when Xavier has exactly two ace and three non-ace).

You merely need to count total outcomes (Zorro is dealt any five from forty-seven cards; when Xavier has two aces and three non ace).

Then divide, as normal (after being assure that all outcomes are equally probable).

$$\dfrac{\mathrm C(2,1)\,\mathrm C(45,4) + \mathrm C(2,2)\,\mathrm C(45,3)}{\mathrm C(47,5)}$$

---

Note: you could also have used that the event of Zorro receiving no aces is the complement of the favoured event.

$$\dfrac{\mathrm C(47,5)-\mathrm C(45,5)}{\mathrm C(47,3)}$$

---

Alternatively we can count ways to place the aces among either the second hand or the remaining forty-two cards in the deck.$$\dfrac{\mathrm C(5,1)\,\mathrm C(42,1)+\mathrm C(5,2)}{\mathrm C(47,2)}$$

These are, of course, equal.

---

> For part (b), I know that to proof independence, I need to proof that P(A|B) = P(A). P(X gets an Ace) = C(4,1)C(48,4)/C(52,5) = 778,320/2,598,960 = 0.2995. As for P(X gets an Ace | Z gets a Spade), I'm not sure how to do because there is one card which is an Ace of Spade. But my sense is they may not be independent, just can't proof it mathematically.

Use the law of total probability, partitioning on whether the Ace of Spades is in Xavier's hand or not.

$${\mathsf P(\spadesuit\in Z\mid A\in X)}={{\mathsf P(\spadesuit\in Z\mid A\spadesuit\in X)\mathsf P(A\spadesuit\in X\mid A\in X)}\\+{\mathsf P(\spadesuit\in Z\mid A\in X, A\spadesuit\notin X)\mathsf P(A\spadesuit\notin X\mid A\in X)}}$$

And of course $\mathsf P(A\spadesuit\in X)=\dfrac{\mathsf P(A\spadesuit\in X)}{\mathsf P(A\in X)}$ and such...

Comment: part 1)  Don't I have to divide it by C(47,5) instead of C(50,5) because X already got 5 cards (2 Aces and 3 non-Ace cards).

part 2) I have been told that if we just know that X has an Ace card without knowing what kind of Ace it is, the event that X has an Ace will be independent of the event that Z has a Spade.  I'm not sure how to rigorously proof that. Please suggest.

Comment: Indeed, @zeclipse .  Good catch.  I've corrected and added a check.